# GOF composite design pattern implementation using modern C++

Tags: c++, design-patterns, c++11, recursion

After reading about the [composite pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composite_pattern) from [*Design Patterns*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns), I thought to re-implement the code mentioned in the motivation section using the modern C++ concept/idioms:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<string>
#include<memory>
#include<algorithm>


/*****************************************/
template<typename T>
void display(const T& val) {
    std::cout << val << "\n";
}


using Watt = double;
using Currency = double;

/*****************************************/
class Equipment {
public:
    using EquipmentSmartPtr = std::shared_ptr<Equipment>;
    virtual ~Equipment() = default;
    std::string Name() { return _name; }
    virtual Watt Power() { return _power; }
    virtual Currency NetPrice() { return _price; }
    // fixed 20% percent discount
    virtual Currency DiscountPrice() { return (0.8*NetPrice()); }
    virtual void Add(EquipmentSmartPtr x) { }
    virtual void Remove(EquipmentSmartPtr x) { }
protected:
    Equipment(std::string n) :_name(n){ }
private:
    std::string _name;
    Watt        _power{ 440 };
    Currency    _price{ 200 };
};


/*****************************************/
class FloopyDisk : public Equipment {
public:
    FloopyDisk(std::string n) :Equipment(n) {}
    virtual ~FloopyDisk() = default;
};


/*****************************************/
class Card : public Equipment {
public:
    Card(std::string n) :Equipment(n) {}
    virtual ~Card() = default;
};



/*****************************************/
//To find out whether items are in the composite objects
class Name_Equal {
private:
    Equipment::EquipmentSmartPtr val;
public:
    Name_Equal(const Equipment::EquipmentSmartPtr& v) :val(v) { }
    bool operator()(const Equipment::EquipmentSmartPtr& x) const { 
        return (x->Name() == val->Name()); 
    }
};


/*****************************************/
class  CompositeEquipment : public Equipment {
public:
    virtual ~CompositeEquipment() = default;
    virtual Watt Power() override;
    virtual Currency NetPrice() override;
    virtual void Add(EquipmentSmartPtr) override;
    virtual void Remove(EquipmentSmartPtr) override;
protected:
    CompositeEquipment(std::string n) : Equipment(n) { }
private:
    void find_equipment(std::vector<EquipmentSmartPtr>&, EquipmentSmartPtr&);
    std::vector<EquipmentSmartPtr>  _equipment;
};

Watt CompositeEquipment::Power() {
    Watt total{};
    for (const auto& itr : _equipment) 
        total += itr->Power();
    total += Equipment::Power();
    return total;
}

Currency CompositeEquipment::NetPrice() {
    Currency total{};
    for (const auto& itr : _equipment) {
        display(itr->Name());
        total += itr->NetPrice();
    }
    total += Equipment::NetPrice();
    return total;
}

void CompositeEquipment::Add(EquipmentSmartPtr entry) {
    _equipment.push_back(entry);
}

void CompositeEquipment::Remove(EquipmentSmartPtr entry) {
    find_equipment(_equipment, entry);
}

void CompositeEquipment::find_equipment(std::vector<EquipmentSmartPtr>& vec, 
    EquipmentSmartPtr& entry){
    Name_Equal eq(entry);
    auto itrpos = std::find_if(std::begin(vec), std::end(vec), eq);
    if (itrpos != std::end(vec)) {
        vec.erase(itrpos);
    }
}


/*****************************************/
class Chassis : public CompositeEquipment {
public:
    Chassis(std::string n) : CompositeEquipment(n) {}
    virtual ~Chassis() = default;
};


/*****************************************/
class Cabinet : public CompositeEquipment {
public:
    Cabinet(std::string n) : CompositeEquipment(n) {}
    virtual ~Cabinet() = default;
};


/*****************************************/
class Bus : public CompositeEquipment {
public:
    Bus(std::string n) : CompositeEquipment(n) {}
    virtual ~Bus() = default;
};




/*****************************************/
Equipment::EquipmentSmartPtr assemble_pc() {
    auto cabinet = std::make_shared<Cabinet>("PC Cabinet");
    auto chassis = std::make_shared<Chassis>("Chassis");
    cabinet->Add(chassis);

    auto bus = std::make_shared<Bus>("MCA Bus");
    auto card = std::make_shared<Card>("16Mbs Token Ring Card");
    bus->Add(card);
    chassis->Add(bus);
    auto floopy = std::make_shared<FloopyDisk>("3.5inch Floopy Disk");
    cabinet->Add(floopy);
    return cabinet;
}


/*****************************************/
int main() {
    auto pc = assemble_pc();
    std::cout << "The PC Name is: " << pc->Name() << "\n";
    std::cout << "The PC parts are: " << "\n";
    auto price = pc->NetPrice();
    std::cout << "The net price of PC is: " << price << "\n";

    return 0;
}
```

To simplify a bit, the "all components have same fixed price and power usage" assumption has been made. Other logic should be self-explanatory and hence not explained here about them.

I would like to get review/opinion on the following points:

- Overall logic used to implement this pattern.
- Uses of `std::shared_ptr` over `std::unique_ptr`.
- Uses of `std::vector`.

Based on my understanding, it should do recursive search in all composite object in which client has invoked and recursively all its child objects which can also be of composite type. Just to illustrate from above implementation, if the client writes it as `cabinet->Remove(bus);`, it would **not** remove the `bus` object as it is the child of `chassis` object. This seems **incorrect** to me. However, I am not able to implement the `CompositeEquipment::Remove` in such a way that it searches recursively if child objects themselves are of composite.

Comment: [My answer to the related question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26569833/434551) would be appropriate here too. But then, it doesn't make sense to create a duplicate answer here.

Answer (score 3):

- These `#include`s:

  > ```
  > #include<iostream>
  > #include<vector>
  > #include<string>
  > #include<memory>
  > #include<algorithm>
  > ```

  look nicer with a space after each `#include` directive:

  ```
  #include <iostream>
  #include <vector>
  #include <string>
  #include <memory>
  #include <algorithm>
  ```
- This may also be nit-picky, but the "border" comments are a bit tacky.  You could instead use that space to provide documentation on the usage.  You could also put these implementations into separate files if they're best organized in that way instead.
- This particular `display()` function serves no useful purpose and is only used in one place.  Beyond that, the name is ambiguous because it doesn't state *what* is to be displayed specifically.  Just remove this function and do the same displaying inline.
- This doesn't look like a good alias:

  > ```
  > using Currency = double;
  > ```

  It's preferred not to use such types with currency due to their precision with regards to values.  Instead, use an integer type such as `int`.  There are many resources online that more specifically state why this is an issue.